# Flex3 VideoDisplay to Flex4 VideoDisplay

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, videodisplay

My Flex3 VideoDisplay is shown below:

```
<extensions:SmoothVideo
        id="vidWin"
        volume="1"
        playheadUpdateInterval="10"
        playheadUpdate="onPlayheadUpdate();"
        bufferTime="0.5"
        width="320" height="240"            
        metadataReceived="onMetaData( event );"/>
```

How do I change is to Flex 4 videoDisplay: as the Flex4 component does not have property for metadataReceived and playheadUpdateInterval and bufferTime.

Thanks in advance

Best
~Z~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Adobe LiveDocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/VideoDisplay.html)

I'm afraid that according to this there is no equivalent for what you are looking for.

Maybe you can have a look at Adobe's [Open Source Media Framework](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/osmf/Open+Source+Media+Framework) for this or just keep on using the `<mx:VideoDisplay>` component within your spark application since flex 4 is backwards compatible.

Cheers